# Retrieve ActivityInfo for Activity Instance

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-manifest

I have an instance of an Activity in a helper class and I'm trying to obtain attributes from its entry in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I can get a list of all of the `ActivityInfo` instances but how do I to target the specific one for my application?

The activity instance is not in the same package as the helper class and not defined in the same manifest (helper class is a library included in the activity's application project).

What I have so far:

```
Activity activity = //the instance
String applicationPackage = activity.getApplicationInfo().packageName;
PackageInfo info = activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : info.activities) {
    if (/* activityInfo applies to our activity instance */) {
        return activityInfo.someProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get information from the Application's manifest file or the Library's manifest?

Comment: The application's manifest which the activity is a member of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding of your question: You need to get the information about a particular Activity within your Application.

Currently you are using `getPackageInfo` to obtain your package information from the package manager, but you don't need to do this if you only care about one Activity within the Application. You can use `getActivityInfo` instead, so long as you know the fully qualified name of the Activity and use a ComponentName, ex: `com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.myactivity`

[PackageManager Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getActivityInfo%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29)

Comment: Woah! I'm not sure how I totally missed this method. I assumed since there was no `getActivityInfo` to match the `getApplicationInfo` on the activity itself that it didn't exit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the information of the current activity

ActivityInfo info = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), 0);